# Autofill form depending on one field in Rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I want to autofill some fields with data from database depending on the value in the first field. 
This is what i have:

```
$(function(){
   $('#request_name').on('focusout', function () {
     var clientName = $(this).val();
     $.ajax({
    url: "/requests/autofill/"+clientName,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: ...some dataType
    })      
   });
});
```

When user types some text into the first field with id "request_name" and focuses out i want to take that value search for it in db and fill some other fields with returned values.

Here is my controller:

```
def autofill
    @client = Client.where("name=?",params[:name]).take
    respond_to do |format|
     ... some code 
    end
   end
```

And route for that:

```
get "requests/autofill/:name" => "requests#autofill", as: :requests_autofill
```

Also i have created autofill.js.erb file in my requests view. I think i should handle filling form fields inside that file.

But, here i do not know how to send proper ajax request to the server and also how to handle it. 
If i don't specify dataType server returns the whole page which is autofill.html.erb. I think i should use some other dataType, but i don't know which one.

Also i want to insert returned values to the form fields.
For example one of the fields to be autofilled looks like that

```
<%= f.text_field :mobile, class: 'form-control' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Client has mobile and your input field id is `mobile_input`, add following script in

**autofill.js.erb**

```
$('#mobile_input").val('<%=@client.mobile%>');
```

Comment: This should work for filling field with some values. But how to make proper ajax request to get these values and pass them to the autofill.js.erb

Comment: I assume the ajax request lands properly in `autofill` action. Here you can collect required data the way you want in instance variables and use them just like suggested above in respectie js.erb templete. Share more details on what data you are going to collect and how you want to display on the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#request_name").on('focusout', function(){              
    $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: "/requests/autofill/"+clientName,
             data: formData,
             success: function(data){
```

//Use the data returned by the API to fill the from fields, like below

```
                      $('#field_id').html(data.<json_key>)     
                    }
    });
    return false;
 });
```

Comment: Kindly remove that  "data: formData"  option.